# How to Access an array of objects properties?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, dom

i'm working in a simple program that uses an HTML Form to fill an Array with some information, so far, i can get the input data, store it into my list, and visualize it like this : [image]

It basically, converts the Name to a Link, when you click it, it will create a `<div>` in which i show all the information of the contact.

And i've done this like this :

The error i'm getting is in the last 6 lines of Code.

(I'm trying to avoid all non-troubling code)

```
var list = [];
var ulList = document.createElement("UL");

function AddToList(){
    //Just pushes the info into the list.
}

function Visualize(){
    ClearScreen();
    for(var i = 0 ; i < list.length ; i++){
        //Tried to keep it clean, this just works with each item in the list.
        AddToList(i);    
    }      
}

//This Works correctly, it shows every Name i've previously pushed into the list like a Link.
function AddToList(index){
    var element = document.createElement("LI");
    var name = document.createTextNode(list[index].name);
    element.appendChild(name);

    var link = document.createElement("A");
    link.setAttribute("HREF", "#");
    link.appendChild(element);
    lik.setAttribute("ID", index);            
    link.addEventListener("click", ShowInfo(this.id)); //Index would do the same

    ulList.appendChild(link);           
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(ulList);    
}

//Trouble comes here
function ShowInfo(index){
    CleanDIV();

    //Previously created <div> with box as id    
    var box = document.getElementById("box");
    var details = document.createElement("UL");
    var lName = document.createElement("LI");
    var lNumber = document.createElement("LI");
    var lMail = document.createElement("LI");


    //
    //The error is here : Cannot Read Property 'name' of undefined
    //And i dont know why, since i've done something similar in a previous line...
    //    
    lName.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Name :" + list[index].name));
    lNumber.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Number : " + list[index].number));
    lMail.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Mail : " + list[index].mail));

    details.appendChild(lName);
    details.appendChild(lNumber);
    detaisl.appendChild(lMail);
}
```

I dont even know what kind of mistake i'm making, and was not sure of how to ask this question.

I apologyze for any grammar mistake, my bad variable naming abilities and any lack of quality in my question.

Thank you kindly.

Comment: What is your question? How to add the properties to an array?

Comment: @Nivas sorry if it was not clear enough, i will edit now, my question was about how to handle the error i got while trying to access the array properties, since i do it without problems in the first lines of the code, but i get errors while doing almost the same in the last lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your AddToList function, indice is 'undefined'

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake while translating my code, Indice should be Index.

Comment: In your function ShowInfo why don't you try putting a `console.log(index);` to see what's in the index variable?

Comment: i'm geting Undefined index in there

Comment: What about if you put `console.log(this.id);` at the beginning of your AddToList function?

Comment: There, you have the answer. `this` variable contains the windows object, not the link element variable or anything like that

Answer (score 0):

You get the error because you have not added anything to your `list` array. Add the person details to the `list` array when the <kbd>Add to List</kbd> button is clicked. And retrieve this when the link is clicked.

```
var name = document.getElementById("txtName").value;
var number = document.getElementById("txtNnumber").value;
...
var person = {'name': name, 'number': number};
list.push(person);
```

Comment: I fill the list very similar to that, but i have no troubles accessing the .name property earlier in the code, i just get the error in the last part

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a couple of typos in your code.

```
lik.setAttribute("ID", indice);            
link.addEventListener("click", ShowInfo(this.id)); //Index would do the same
```

should be

```
link.setAttribute("ID", index);            
link.addEventListener("click", ShowInfo(index)); //Index would do the same
```

Comment: Yes, sorry, i have the original code in Spanish so i had to translate it bit by bit, must have skipped that, sorry

Comment: It might be helpful to get a working fiddle set up.
This error would occur if there is nothing in the list at the index you provided (or if the variable 'index' was not properly defined)